# Trading bot ERROR: mexc {"code":10007,"msg":"symbol not support api"}

Tags: python, bots, cryptocurrency

I have this python script and I use mexc API and I want to trade BTC/USDT but when I run the script I get this error ERROR: mexc {"code":10007,"msg":"symbol not support api"}

here is the script

```
import ccxt
import time

# Trading pair and time frame
SYMBOL = 'BTC/USDT'
TIMEFRAME = '1m'
TRADE_SYMBOL = SYMBOL.replace('/', '')

# Trading amount and risk
TRADE_AMOUNT = 0.0025
RISK_PER_TRADE = 0.01
BALANCE = 250

# Exchange API keys
API_KEY = 'api key'
SECRET_KEY = 'secret key'
```

I found mexc symbol list and BTC/USDT was there so it should work but it doesn't

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation *for the API*?

Comment: According to MEXC [annoucement](https://support.mexc.com/hc/en-001/articles/15149585234969-MEXC-Upgrade-and-Maintenance-of-API-for-BTC-USDT-FTM-USDT-OP-USDT-DOGE-USDT) the API for the BTC/USDT pair was disabled by the exchange

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue where the BTC/USDT trading pair was not available for use through the Mexc API. It appears that in the Apikey configuration, there is a whitelist of approved trading pairs that must be manually added before they can be accessed through the API. As a workaround, I tested the LBTC/USDT pair and it worked successfully. I hope this information is useful to you.

[image]

Comment: The trading pairs API setting is optional but it's absurd that MEXC doesn't permit trading of BTC, ETH, and other major coins through the API.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. It looks like the pair you are trying to use is not a valid trading pair supported by the api. I have checked the list of the provided pairs and found that BTC/USDC is the closest alternative, which worked for me.